# Pagination function with get pageid

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I working on pagination script and i have problem about getting pageid..
I have something like 
   **http://domain.com/section/5/forum/958752&p=2**

&p= is page number everything with a script is okay only when set p empty or 0 getting mysql error. Theres also problem with link if i open link without &p=2 i getting error..

viewtopic.php code:

```
        $p_id = (int) (!isset($_GET["p"]) ? 1 : $_GET["p"]);    

        $limit = 1;
        $startpoint = ($p_id * $limit) - $limit;
                    //to make pagination
        $statement = "`topics` WHERE sid='$sid' AND fid='$url'";    

        mysql_query("SELECT * FROM {$statement} ORDER BY lastanswer DESC LIMIT {$startpoint} , {$limit}") or die(mysql_error());
```

I using htacess for this link its like:

```
        RewriteRule ^section/(.*)/forum/(.*)$           "/index.php?page=viewforum&sid=$1&url=$2"
```

I just want in this to make if someone open normal link like 
http://domain.com/section/5/forum/958752 to open normal page with pagination ,  if user set to &p= empty or 0 to die... I tryed a lot of methods but i didnt get a real result..